# ms-access/database - How to handle deprecated items which are still needed

Tags: database, ms-access, relational-database

I am wondering how to handle entries in a database which should not exist anymore but are still necessary for dependent tables.

Example: I have one table for parking spots, one for cars, and one for the time when a car parked in a specific spot. I want to keep track when which car was on which slot. Lets assume one day one of the parking slots will get removed.

What now? If I delete the spot in the table and I make use of referential integrity all entries from the past associated with this slot will vanish, that's not acceptable. But if I remove the referential integrity and only delete the slot I will have a lot of orphaned entries in the table which stores the entries when which car was parked in a spot.

I am pretty sure there must be a simple answer to handle this problem but unfortunately I was not able to specify the problem good enough to find a solution on stackoverflow/Google. Therefore I have to ask.

Comment: do not delete, but mark as deleted with additional column

Comment: Try asking on [Stack Exchange - Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) forum.  Not only is this topic germane to that forum, it is probably too broad for a Stack Overflow question.  Perhaps you're correct that the solution need not be overly complicated, but there are likely many, many useful solutions, all of which can lead to different, opinionated answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you would just put a flag on in the "parking space" table that says whether it is active or not.  Well, actually, perhaps not just a flag, but a date when it is first available and a date when it is no longer available.

Incorporating this into a data model is a bit trickier.  In MS Access, I would recommend that you do the date check when attempting to insert references to the space.  This can be handled with a trigger.